# UPDATE script not working - 0 Rows Affected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have an SQL Server database and i am trying to run an update script on one of the tables but it keeps saying "0 Rows Affected".

If i run the following script it says "33 Rows Affected"

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID = 19
```

But if i run the following script it says "0 Rows Affected":

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID = 19
AND ProductID = 20
AND ProductID = 23
AND ProductID = 24
AND ProductID = 25
AND ProductID = 27
AND ProductID = 28
AND ProductID = 29
AND ProductID = 30
AND ProductID = 31
AND ProductID = 32
AND ProductID = 33
AND ProductID = 54
AND ProductID = 55
AND ProductID = 56
AND ProductID = 57
AND ProductID = 58
AND ProductID = 64
AND ProductID = 71
AND ProductID = 72
AND ProductID = 73
AND ProductID = 74
AND ProductID = 75
AND ProductID = 77
AND ProductID = 105
AND ProductID = 109
AND ProductID = 152
AND ProductID = 157
AND ProductID = 158
AND ProductID = 162
AND ProductID = 164
AND ProductID = 165
AND ProductID = 167
AND ProductID = 169
AND ProductID = 170
AND ProductID = 173
AND ProductID = 174
```

What am i doing wrong here?

I am certain the productIDs have a IsDefault = 1 and Published = 1, which is why i want to run the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is the use of AND.
Think about it: a product cannot have at the same time different IDs; what you want is update different products, one for each id.
So you have to use OR:

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID = 19
OR ProductID = 20
OR ProductID = 23
OR ProductID = 24
...
```

A compact syntax is:

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID IN (19, 20, 23, 24, ....)
```

Comment: Thanks you gave an explaination and you gave me to clear examples. I have mark your answer as my chosen solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Your WHERE clause is faulty. You don't want to update the row where the productID is ALL of those id's (since there can only be one ProductID per row, so your WHERE statement will never be true), but one by one. You should use IN instead, like so:

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID IN ( 19, 20, 23 ... etc);
```

That will update all of the rows individually.

Answer (score 1):

User OR instead. You're saying that ProductID should be 19, 20, ... at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Well i would think the problem is you are and-ing all your id's together IE a product has an id of 162 OR 164 but not both.

Try your statement using an IN, ie:

WHERE ProductID IN (19,20,21,22 ETC)

Should have more luck!

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Change all `AND` to `OR`
2. Use the `IN` clause

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[ProductVariant]   
SET [IsDefault] = 0,
    [Published] = 0
WHERE ProductID in (19, 20, 23....164)
```